# How to parse JSON data into android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-json

How do I parse below JSON data in android and I want to display it in a recycler view

```
{"scode":"200","video_limit":"4","app_category":{"cat1":{"app_menu_id":"19","app_menu_name":"Love","video":[{"app_video_id":"1","app_video_name":"video1","app_video_path":"vid1.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid1.jpg","app_menu_id":"19","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Love"},{"app_video_id":"2","app_video_name":"vid2","app_video_path":"vid2.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid2.jpg","app_menu_id":"19","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Love"},{"app_video_id":"4","app_video_name":"vid3","app_video_path":"vid3.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid3.jpg","app_menu_id":"19","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Love"},{"app_video_id":"5","app_video_name":"vid4","app_video_path":"vid4.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid4.jpg","app_menu_id":"19","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Love"}]},"cat2":{"app_menu_id":"21","app_menu_name":"Sad","video":[{"app_video_id":"3","app_video_name":"vid5","app_video_path":"vid5.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid5.jpg","app_menu_id":"21","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Sad"},{"app_video_id":"6","app_video_name":"vid6","app_video_path":"vid6.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid6.jpg","app_menu_id":"21","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Sad"},{"app_video_id":"8","app_video_name":"vid7","app_video_path":"vid7.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid7.jpg","app_menu_id":"21","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Sad"},{"app_video_id":"9","app_video_name":"vid8","app_video_path":"vid8.mp4","app_video_image_path":"vid8.jpg","app_menu_id":"21","app_sub_menu_id":"0","app_menu_name":"Sad"}]}}}
```

Comment: use some libraries like gson, create some classes for your data, create custom adapter for your recyclerview, and you can find many 'how to ...' for each of this tasks

Answer (score -1):

Use GsonConverter

https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson

the code bellow is the usage of it.

```
public class Action {

@SerializedName("uuid")
private String uuid;

@SerializedName("type")
private String type;

@SerializedName("celebrity_base")
private CelebrityBase celebrity_base;

@SerializedName("topic")
private Topic topic;

@SerializedName("profession")
private Profession profession;

@SerializedName("movie")
private Movie movie;

@SerializedName("album")
private Album album;

@SerializedName("track")
private Track track;

@SerializedName("tournament")
private Tournament tournament;

@SerializedName("match")
private Match match;

@SerializedName("book")
private Book book;

@SerializedName("hashtags")
private List<HashTag> hashTags;

@SerializedName("target_persons")
@Expose
private List<TargetPersons> targetPersons;

@SerializedName("top_comments")
private List<TopComment> actionComments;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("subtitle")
private String subtitle;

@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

@SerializedName("from_date")
private String from_date;

@SerializedName("to_date")
private String to_date;

@SerializedName("rate")
private double rate;

@SerializedName("rate_count")
private int rate_count;

@SerializedName("persian_rate")
private String persian_rate;

@SerializedName("persian_rate_count")
private String persian_rate_count;

@SerializedName("image_link")
private String image_link;

@SerializedName("picture")
private String picture;

@SerializedName("relation_type")
private String relation_type;

@SerializedName("persian_user_rate")
private int persian_user_rate;

@NonNull
public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(@NonNull String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

@NonNull
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(@NonNull String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Nullable
public CelebrityBase getCelebrity_base() {
    return celebrity_base;
}

public void setCelebrity_base(@Nullable CelebrityBase celebrity_base) {
    this.celebrity_base = celebrity_base;
}

@Nullable
public Topic getTopic() {
    return topic;
}

public void setTopic(@Nullable Topic topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}

@Nullable
public Profession getProfession() {
    return profession;
}

public void setProfession(@Nullable Profession profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}

@Nullable
public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(@Nullable Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

@Nullable
public Album getAlbum() {
    return album;
}

public void setAlbum(@Nullable Album album) {
    this.album = album;
}

@Nullable
public Track getTrack() {
    return track;
}

public void setTrack(@Nullable Track track) {
    this.track = track;
}

@Nullable
public Tournament getTournament() {
    return tournament;
}

public void setTournament(@Nullable Tournament tournament) {
    this.tournament = tournament;
}

@Nullable
public Match getMatch() {
    return match;
}

public void setMatch(@Nullable Match match) {
    this.match = match;
}

@Nullable
public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(@Nullable Book book) {
    this.book = book;
}

@Nullable
public List<HashTag> getHashTags() {
    return hashTags;
}

public void setHashTags(@Nullable List<HashTag> hashTags) {
    this.hashTags = hashTags;
}

@Nullable
public List<TopComment> getActionComments() {
    return actionComments;
}

public void setActionComments(@Nullable List<TopComment> actionComments) {
    this.actionComments = actionComments;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Nullable
public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public void setSubtitle(@Nullable String subtitle) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
}

@Nullable
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(@Nullable String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Nullable
public String getFrom_date() {
    return from_date;
}

public void setFrom_date(@Nullable String from_date) {
    this.from_date = from_date;
}

@Nullable
public String getTo_date() {
    return to_date;
}

public void setTo_date(@Nullable String to_date) {
    this.to_date = to_date;
}

@Nullable
public double getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(@Nullable double rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

@Nullable
public int getRate_count() {
    return rate_count;
}

public void setRate_count(@Nullable int rate_count) {
    this.rate_count = rate_count;
}

@Nullable
public String getPersian_rate() {
    return persian_rate;
}

public void setPersian_rate(@Nullable String persian_rate) {
    this.persian_rate = persian_rate;
}

@Nullable
public String getPersian_rate_count() {
    return persian_rate_count;
}

public void setPersian_rate_count(@Nullable String persian_rate_count) {
    this.persian_rate_count = persian_rate_count;
}

@Nullable
public String getImage_link() {
    return image_link;
}

public void setImage_link(@Nullable String image_link) {
    this.image_link = image_link;
}

@Nullable
public String getPicture() {
    return picture;
}

public void setPicture(@Nullable String picture) {
    this.picture = picture;
}

@Nullable
public String getRelation_type() {
    return relation_type;
}

public void setRelation_type(@Nullable String relation_type) {
    this.relation_type = relation_type;
}

@Nullable
public int getPersian_user_rate() {
    return persian_user_rate;
}

public void setPersian_user_rate(@Nullable int persian_user_rate) {
    this.persian_user_rate = persian_user_rate;
}

public List<TargetPersons> getTargetPersons() {
    return targetPersons;
}

public void setTargetPersons(List<TargetPersons> targetPersons) {
    this.targetPersons = targetPersons;
}
}
```